# cpu frequency scaling isn't working, but did before

Tags: 13.10

I have an AMD 8320 on a MSI 990FXA-GD80 V2

I was doing some tweaking to my BIOs trying to increase power and what not and everything is fine in that regard, but upon reboot my CPU Frequency Scaling Indicator reports my CPU doesn't support frequency scaling even though previously this was working.

I tried returning BIOs settings to factory defaults, but it refuses to work.

How can I get my frequency scaling back?

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 2
model name  : AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x6000822
cpu MHz     : 3762.510
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 7525.02
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to leave this answer here for anyone that is really having problems, but it should be noted that knowing the exact setting in BIOs would be nice and I will make that as the answer if anyone knows.

I removed my motherboard battery to do a hard reset since obviously the reset to factory settings in the bios wasn't actually doing a reset.

Everything works as it should now.